# We want a program that will allow us to print a “grade list” of the students in a class

Tags: python, average

Class Grade List – PYTHON

I really don't know where to get started with this. I realize it's basic, but if someone could walk me through this it would be greatly appreciated.

￼We want a program that will allow us to print a “grade list” of the students in a class.
The program should loop, asking for a name, midterm score, and final score. It should then echo the input, and print the information entered, plus the student’s average.
To exit the loop, the user enters ”done” in lower case. The program will print the class average and then terminate.

Comment: Start by making a class called gradebook, a class called student (which has name, midterm, and final score as properties), and put functions in your class gradebook which use raw_input to get info for each student. When you get stuck post the code you have tried.

Answer (score 3):

Start by translating one part of the description at a time into Python.

```
while True:
    ask for a name, midterm score, and final score
    echo the input
    print the information entered, plus the student's average
    to exit the loop, the user enters "done" in lower case
print the class average and terminate
```

Then:

```
while True:
    name = input('Name')
    if name == 'done':
        break
    midterm = input('Midterm score')
    final = input('Final score')
    average = the student's average
    print('Name', name, 
          'Midterm score', midterm, 'Final score', final, 'Average', average)
class_average = ???
print('Class average', class_average)
```

Calculating the student's average is easy—you have to convert `midterm` and `final` to numbers, then average those numbers.

Calculating the class average is trickier. But if you could append each score to some kind of collection that you could sum up later—or figure out which smaller set of numbers you need to keep track of without needing the whole collection—it's not that hard.